# Customize .mod.c MODULE_ALIAS in Linux Kernel Module

Tags: linux, module, compilation, kernel, driver

I need to modify a kernel module located in Linux 3.2.0. Within `drivers/staging/bcm`, the driver should support the device id `198F:015E`, instead in the `InterfaceInit.h` file, it was mentioned as `198F:15E`, I changed that to `015E` but still, after successful compilation, the new device id's are not being picked up by the kernel.

Here is the output of `modinfo`:

```
filename:       <somewhere/>bcm_wimax.ko
license:        GPL
version:        5.2.45
description:    Beceem Communications Inc. WiMAX driver
srcversion:     D6016018ABCFFD16AF31D22
alias:          usb:v19D2p0007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0489pE017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v19D2p0132d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v198FpBCCDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v198Fp0220d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v198Fp0210d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v198Fp0300d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (uint)
```

My `198F:015E` is still not appearing! Strangely after beginning the compilation, I can see a file called bcm_wimax.mod.c getting generated inside the module source folder. Inside that, I found out the `modinfo` alias thing. Which looks like:

```c
 #include <linux/module.h>
 #include <linux/vermagic.h>
 #include <linux/compiler.h>

 MODULE_INFO(vermagic, VERMAGIC_STRING);

 struct module __this_module
 __attribute__((section(".gnu.linkonce.this_module"))) = {
  .name = KBUILD_MODNAME,
  .init = init_module,
 #ifdef CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD
  .exit = cleanup_module,
 #endif
  .arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,
 };

 MODULE_INFO(staging, "Y");

 static const struct modversion_info ____versions[]
 __used
 __attribute__((section("__versions"))) = {
 };

 static const char __module_depends[]
 __used
 __attribute__((section(".modinfo"))) =
 "depends=";

 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v198Fp0300d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");
 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v198Fp0210d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");
 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v198Fp0220d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");
 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v198FpBCCDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");
 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v19D2p0132d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");
 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v0489pE017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");
 MODULE_ALIAS("usb:v19D2p0007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*");

 MODULE_INFO(srcversion, "D6016018ABCFFD16AF31D22");
```

But I tried to modify `bcm_wimax.mod.c` but after compiling, the file got reverted back to it's original condition, removing my edits. How can I get to add my `198f:015e` to the module alias section?

Comment: you should not modify a generated file actually. I don't have a banglalion modem to test this out. If i can find anything reading kernel source, i will post it. besides why 3.2.0 when latest 3.5-rc7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`198F:015E` is the same as `198F:15E`

Looking at the kernel source it seems you are interested in `BCM_USB_PRODUCT_ID_SYM`, but the device is not present in `InterfaceUsbtable` `drivers/staging/bcm/InterfaceInit.c`.

You can add it and hope the driver support that device as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, you just found the missing piece of the puzzle!